# JTextArea Почему выбивает Exception: For input string: ""?

Tags: java, swing, строки

Хочу вводить число в JTextArea и что бы оно выводилось на единицу больше. Нужно что бы это был именно int в промежутке между выводами.

```
public class PPANEL extends JPanel
{
    public PPANEL()
    {
```

`setLayout(null);
        JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
        txt.setBounds(100, 30, 100, 20);
        add(txt);
        String txtdata = txt.getText();

        int num = Integer.parseInt(txtdata)+1;

        JButton calc = new JButton("CALC");
        calc.setBounds(100,100,100,20);
        add(calc);
        calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                txt.append(String.valueOf(txtdata));
            }
        });
    }`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public PPANEL() {
    setLayout(null);
    JTextArea txt = new JTextArea("0");
    txt.setBounds(100, 30, 100, 20);
    add(txt);
    JButton calc = new JButton("CALC");
    calc.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 20);
    add(calc);
    calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText()) + 1;
            txt.setText(num + "");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменять значение поля вот так

```
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setText(txtData);
```