# Как в одной строке JTextField ввести данные для new Person(130, "Hasia", "Polubkin", 23)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Есть что-то типа БД. Есть одна строка `JTextField` которая заполняется данными после нажатия соответствующей кнопки. Как можно реализовать заполнение нескольких колонов типа (int, String, String, int) в одной строке за одно нажатие кнопки? То есть, как-то оделить что ли при вводе.

```
JTextField txtCreate = new JTextField(); //CREATE
txtCreate.setBounds(10, 350, 100, 20);
String temp[] = textCreate.getText().replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
add(txtCreate);
add(btnCreate);
btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Person();
                dm.pd.create(new Person(new Person(Integer.valueOf(temp[0]), temp[1], temp[2], Integer.valueOf(temp[3]))); //HELP
                    dm.pp = dm.pd.read(); tbl.revalidate();
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотря в каком виде вы данные собираетесь вводить в то поле, можно их разделить запятой, т.е. 12, VASYA, PUPKIN, 20.
Потом

```
String temp[] = textCreate.getText().replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
```

и соответственно

```
dm.pd.create(new Person(Integer.valueOf(temp[0]), temp[1], temp[2], Integer.valueOf(temp[3])));
```

Ну и проверки сделать на правильный ввод

Comment: О, Отлично! Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Кстати, еще нужно будет пробелы убрать, чтобы ошибок не кидало.
String temp[] = textCreate.getText().replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");

Comment: Выбивает исключение на For input string: "".

Comment: Скинь код и данные, которые вводишь в поле

Comment: Может это поможет http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530635/jtextarea-Почему-выбивает-exception-for-input-string

Comment: 12, VASYA, PUPKIN, 20 и есть эти данные. Я добавил изменения в код,